# Extract json response to shell variable using jq

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I have a sample json response as shown below which i am trying to parse using jq in shell script.`[{"id":1,"notes":"Demo1\nDemo2"}]`

This is the command through which I am trying to access notes in the shell script.

```
value=($(curl $URL | jq -r '.[].notes'))
```

When I echo "$value" I only get Demo1. How to get the exact value: Demo1\nDemo2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, there is no backslash or `n` in the notes field. `\n` is JSON's way of encoding a literal linefeed, so the value you should be expecting is:

```
Demo1
Demo2
```

The issue you're seeing is because you have split the value on whitespace and created an array. Each value can be accessed by index:

```
$ cat myscript
data='[{"id":1,"notes":"Demo1\nDemo2"}]'
value=($(printf '%s' "$data" | jq -r '.[].notes'))
echo "The first value was ${value[0]} and the second ${value[1]}"

$ bash myscript
The first value was Demo1 and the second Demo2
```

To instead get it as a simple string, remove the parens from `value=(..)`:

```
$ cat myscript2
data='[{"id":1,"notes":"Demo1\nDemo2"}]'
value=$(printf '%s' "$data" | jq -r '.[].notes')
echo "$value"

$ bash myscript2
Demo1
Demo2
```

Comment: If you *did* want to read into an array, less buggy to use `readarray` or `mapfile` if targeting bash 4.0, or `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a value < <(jq -r '.[].notes' <<<"$data" && printf '\0')` for bash 3.2 (which also passes through a nonzero exit status should `jq` fail); that way we aren't expanding globs, or splitting on spaces inside individual notes vs. only the newlines.